# How important is hardware compatibility with Linux when running it on VMWare player with a Windows 7 host?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux

I will be getting a laptop provided to me for training which requires running Kali Linux through VMWare Player.  We are primarily a Windows shop and as such I'm not sure how compatible the laptops are with Linux.  My understanding is that with VMWare Player, this shouldn't be a concern for me.  Otherwise I'll be needing to work with IT to see which laptop in stock is most compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to be concerned with Linux being compatible with the VMware virtual hardware, not the actual hardware of the laptop. VMware Player (all VMware products, really) handle Linux quite well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, but for best performance it's strictly recommended to have hardware support for virtualization.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization for more details.
My personal preference is Intel, you can find CPU with virtualization support here: http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced?s=t&VTX=true